# What is the good notion of supervariety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, smooth-manifolds, supermanifolds

The principal (I think) difference between the notions of manifold in differential (including complex analytic) topology and in algebraic (or especially arithmetic) geometry is that for the former the "local models" are the same while for the latter they may vary.

This somehow suggests that there may be a version of the notion of supervariety in algebraic/arithmetic geometry, which has variable local models too. Except that I have no idea what these local models can be.

Has this been investigated?

Comment: There's the theory of dg-schemes and, more generally, derived schemes. They are the algebraic analog of NQ-supermanifolds.

Comment: @user40276 Thank you for the interesting comment. I would be happy to accept an answer with some references, and, preferably, an explanation of how derived schemes relate to supermanifolds. What I mean is primarily an explanation of how superstructure on the local model can be promoted to a dg-structure: whether there are natural examples of supermanifolds coming from, say, even/odd parts of de Rham, such kinds of things. Could you do it?

Comment: You just take the differential to be zero.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the local models varying in algebraic geometry but not in differential topology? You mean "the" site is more complicated in AG?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan so then the whole superlinear algebra apparatus has some dg-refinement? Like, say, the Berezinian - what does it correspond to in the dg-context?

Comment: @ArturJackson I just meant that a manifold in the sense of differential topology is a sheaved space locally isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ with the sheaf of smooth functions; while in algebraic geometry in general the sheaf is only required to be a sheaf of local rings. Even, say, for smooth varieties over a field one may thus get various regular local algebras over various extensions over that field as stalks of the sheaf.

Comment: It's what Qiaochu said. A scheme is locally of the form $(Spec (B_0), B_0)$ where $B_0$ is some $A$-algebra. A superscheme would be something like $(Spec (B_0), B_0 \oplus B_1)$ where $B_0 \oplus B_1$ is a commutative super $A$-algebra. When this grading actually comes from a $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$-grading by using the odd and even parts, it's called a $N$-superscheme. If furthermore you have a differential (or, equivalently, an odd vector field $Q$, where $[Q, Q] = 0$) it becomes a NQ-superscheme or dg-scheme.

Comment: I've just realized now that there's a nlab page about superschemes  https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/super-scheme

Comment: @user40276 Thank you, this is certainly the answer, especially the treatment in the Kapranov-Vasserot paper referenced there.